# I am unable to login in "User matching query does not exist. Lookup parameters were

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

My view is index and is as follows

```
def index(request):    
if request.method=="POST":
    print "Received POST"
    form=LoginForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        print "FORM is Valid"
        # user registration or login code
        username,pwd=request.POST.get("username",None),request.POST.get("password")
        if not username or not pwd:
            return HttpResponse("Username or password not present")
        try:
            user=User.objects.get(username__exact=username)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist,ex:
            print "Creating new user..."
            user=User.objects.create_user(username,username,pwd)
        if user:
            print "Authenticating..."
            user=authenticate(username=username,password=pwd)
        print "Logging in user"
        login(request,user)
        return redirect("dashboard")
    else:
        print "FORM is NOT VALID"
        template=loader.get_template("index.html")
        rc=RequestContext(request,{'username':'Atul','form':form})
        return HttpResponse(template.render(rc))
else:
    template=loader.get_template("index.html")
    rc=RequestContext(request,{'username':'Atul','form':LoginForm()})
    return HttpResponse(template.render(rc))
```

I have set sqlite3 database file in data direction inside my project directory, even though I am superuser I am unable to login it shows the following error:[![Image showing error][1]][1]

Please Help me out , any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please post the actual text of the stack trace rather than a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error page shows a different error from your code.

The error:

```
user = User.objects.get(username=username)
```

Your Code:

```
user=User.objects.get(username__exact=username)
```

It seems that your web server runs an old version of your code. Try restarting your web server.

Other suggestions:

Try using `except User.DoesNotExist, ex:` instead of `except ObjectDoesNotExist,ex:`

Use [SQLite Database Browser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/) to see if your user exists in db or not. Maybe the first time that you executed `python manage.py syncdb` you haven't specified a main user. To solve it, delete the database.db (with sqlite3), Then run `python manage.py syncdb` one more time